# UITableView and AutoLayout - no table shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm creating a UITableView in code and I'd like to set up the size with constraints - but no tableView is shown:

```
_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:_tableView];

NSDictionary *views = @{ @"tableView": self.tableView};
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[tableView]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[tableView]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

Only without constraints and if I use `initWithFrame:self.view.bounds` the table is shown... what am I missing?

**EDIT:** it doesn't help if I'm initializing the tableView with `self.view.bounds`

**EDIT 2:** Everything seems to be fine if I delete `self.view.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` which I also have in my viewDidLoad - why isn't that allowed?

Comment: Just Try to init the tableView Like : [UITableView alloc] init];

Comment: doesn't change anything :(

Comment: **Discussion -** The rectangle is standardized and then the inset parameters are applied. If the resulting rectangle would have a negative height or width, a null rectangle is returned.

Comment: [self.view addSubview:_tableView]; adding the nil frame to the view . What is the Use, Then..?

Comment: see my edit; if I'm initializing the view with some 'valid' frame and change the constraints afterward's, it isn't displayed either :(

Comment: Are you instantiating the array `constraints`? From the code, the array will be nil. i.e. put `NSLog(@"%@", constraints);` after adding the constraints. I suspect it will be nil.

Comment: Show the UITableView Delegate methods

Comment: @Fogmeister yes, the constraints-array is instatiated, it's just not shown here.

Comment: @Mutawe the delegate methods can't be part of the problem, as everything works if I don't use the constraints.

Comment: where are you putting this code?

Comment: @Fogmeister: into `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Oh! Obvious answer (I think). Will edit my answer. Actually no. Don't know. Sorry man :(

Comment: Why are you removing the constraints from self.view? What happens if you set a breakpoint in viewDidLayoutSubviews and examine the code? What's the frame and view hierarchy like then?

Comment: removing the constraints is nonsense, but it doesn't change anything if I don't. The tableview's frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is x=10, y=10, width=height=0.

Comment: That sounds to me like the superview's frame is zero, and you should be getting layout exceptions in the console.

Comment: @jrturton - no layout exceptions in console...

Comment: Ok, well then the problem is elsewhere. There's nothing wrong with the code in your question, and that's all we have to go on. Can you add more code or put a sample project somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

> Everything seems to be fine if I delete self.view.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; which I also have in my viewDidLoad - why isn't that allowed?

I'm glad you found the answer - here's an explanation for you.

For view controller views that are managed by the system, including but not limited to:

- The root view controller of the window
- A view controller pushed onto a navigation controller
- One of the options in a tab bar controller

You don't want to turn on autolayout. The size and position of `view` is not up to the view controller to decide in these circumstances, and you don't know how the containing object is sizing your view. If it wants to use autolayout, it will turn off the autoresizing mask translation property itself.

The only time you'd make your view controller's view an autolayout view is if you were using it as a child view controller in another view controller, and you wanted to use constraints to size and position the child view controller's view. Even in that case you'd probably not set the property within the view controller, but let the parent do it.

You don't need to turn on autolayout for every view in your hierarchy. Autolayout views can live quite happily inside "legacy layout" views.

Comment: I don't quite understand your anwser, why system doesn't show uitableview when I set self.tableviw.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

Comment: That's not what this question was about. He has the main view of the view controller set to auto layout, which usually isn't right. If you have a different setup, ask a different question.